# Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I am trying to play jwplayer videos in my react project, and as [documentation](https://docs.jwplayer.com/players/docs/jw8-add-a-player-library#cloud-hosted-by-jwp-with-api-calls) suggested I am adding the below code in my public index.html file:

```
<script
      src="http://localhost:3000/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"
      type="text/jsx"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer.key =
        "+1bANyiZkLQznP2yV8ky+2NgQqiQmMg3/Sc0tJdhWUPtP51/8zGnxqqw=";
</script>
```

But getting the above refernce error. Is there any way i can resolve this issue or if any one has integrated the **Self-hosted** jwplayer in their react js projects.